# Create logical variable in new column in R based of rows.

Tags: r

In the dataframe "hive1_phase2" I want to make a new column titled "wifi" with the value "0" in rows 1:141960, "1" from "141961:413614" and "0" again from 413615:632161 (the last row)

What would be the correct code? Mine is not working.

```
hive1_phase2$wifi <- rep(0,(1:141960)(hive1_phase2)
```

rep(1,(141961:413614)(hive1_phase2))
rep(0,(413614:632161)(hive1_phase2))

Thanks!

Comment: `hive1_phase2$wifi = ifelse(rownames(hive1_phase2) %in% 141961:413614, 1, 0)`

Comment: The way to do it with `rep` would be: `rep(c(0,1,0), c(141961, 413614-141961, 632161-413614))`

Comment: Both work! Thanks so much eipi10. I am fairly (read: very) new to R. thanks again

Comment: You don't necessarily need `rep`, just assign `0` to the entire column then insert the `1`s where needed.  `hive1_phase2$wifi <- 0; hive1_phase2$wifi[141961:413614] <- 1`